# send event from server to an ios app

Tags: ios

I would like to know whether there is an alternative different than what I am thinking so far. I have an ios app, which gets data from my server, when the user clicks refresh button or so.

Now, I want to send data from server to the app - for example when an event started so as to update the label on that event.

I have thought of the following :

- Use background fetch from my IOS app and connect to the server every an interval
- Send a push notification and make the user open the app, and the app calls refresh

Is there any other way? Is it possible that server will send the data (just like a push notification) but without the notification to be visible, without firing the app, I just want to change some of its data - an approach similar to the Google Cloud Messaging for Android.

To visualise what I am saying, if you have used LiveScores app, it updates for example the minute of a live match - I want something similar.

I guess I need to follow approach 1, with background fetch (which became more effective in ios7) but just out of curiosity if there is any other solution out there.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the purpose of your app. If it is appropriate, you could try maintaining a keep-alive connection to your server. As for the LiveScores app, I believe it fetches data from the server at regular intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under ios7+ you can do silent pushes (which aren't displayed) [see a nice tutorial — [hayageek.com: iOS Silent Push notifications](http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/)]

Under ios6 and below you are of of luck